# Problema al enviar un dato por GET en PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, get

Tengo un perfil de usuario al que se accede previo registro.

En el perfil hay un *input* para introducir un titulo y un *button* para enviarlo a la base de datos **MySQL**. Ambos elementos se encuentran en un formulario que envía la información por **GET**.

Mi objetivo es que la base de datos almacene el titulo introducido en el *input*.

El problema es que el archivo **.php** que se encarga de realizar el envío de la *query* a la BBDD no recibe el valor introducido en el campo. En cambio, si introduzco cualquier información de manera manual en el código sí me la almacena.

Me gustaría saber qué puede estar ocurriendo.

Muchas Gracias.

**ESTE ES EL CÓDIGO CORRESPONDIENTE AL PERFIL DE USUARIO**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Kanban</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="perfil_style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <?php

        session_start();

        if(!isset($_SESSION["usuario"])){

            header("location: index.php");
        }
    ?>

    <div id="main">
        
        <header>
            <h1>Kanban Personal</h1>

            <form action='cierre_sesion.php'>
                <input type="submit" id="CerrarSesionButton" name="CerrarSesionButton" class="btn_AddPaper" value="Cerrar Sesión"/>
            </form>

            <?php 

                echo $_SESSION["usuario"];

            ?>

        </header>


        <div id="AddPaperDiv">
            <form name="formulario" method="get" action="registro_papers.php">
                <input type=text id="AddPaperInput" class="TituloPaper" name="NombrePaper">
                <button type="submit" id="AddPaperButton" class="btn_AddPaper">Añadir Paper</button> 
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="niveles">
                
                <div id="espera" class="nivel">
                    <label>En Espera</label>
                </div>
                <div id="progreso" class="nivel">
                    <label>En Progreso</label>
                </div>
                <div id="ejecutado" class="nivel">
                    <label>Ejecutado</label>
                </div>
                
        </div>

    </div>

    <script src="perfil_script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**ESTE ES EL CÓDIGO DEL ARCHIVO QUE SE ENCARGA DE REGISTRAR LA QUERY EN MYSQL**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php

        require_once("datos_conexion.php");


        $reg_paper = $_GET["NombrePaper"];


        $conexion = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass);
    
        if(mysqli_connect_errno()){

            echo "Fallo al conectar a la BBDD";

            exit();
        }


        mysqli_select_db($conexion, $db_name) or die ("No se encuentra la BBDD");

        mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8");
 
        $query = "INSERT INTO PAPERS (PAPER_NOMBRE) VALUES('$reg_paper')";



        $res = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);

        if($res == false){

            echo "Error en el registro";


        }else{

            echo "Paper registrado";

        }

        
        mysqli_close($conexion);


    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hay 3 cosas que deberías tener en cuenta:**

1. Utiliza siempre el método *POST* en vez de *GET* para envío de formularios en PHP. Es más efectivo y seguro.
2. Utiliza el mismo valor para las etiquetas {*id*} y {*name*} de un input, salvo que exista algún código en Jquery en el que sea un embrollo utilizar el mismo valor para ambas etiquetas.
3. Si el resultado de una operación en PHP sirve sólo para mostrar un mensaje en particular, es recomendable hacer todo el proceso en una sola página y no en dos.

**Siguiendo con las cuestiones mencionadas, lo que deberías hacer es:**

**Primer punto**: Cambiar la línea del formulario estableciendo el método *POST* y el action que lleve el mismo nombre del archivo PHP que corresponde al perfil de usuario. Como no mencionas cómo se llama tu archivo de perfiles de usuarios, vamos a suponer que el nombre sea *perfil_usuario.php* en el que accedes a los perfiles de usuarios. Entonces, la línea del formulario sería:

```
<form name="formulario" method="post" action="perfil_usuario.php">
```

Como puedes notarlo, lo que haremos al hacer el submit al formulario es enviar los datos a la misma página, pero con una notable diferencia que podrás verlo más adelante de este mensaje.

**Segundo punto**: Cambiar el valor de las etiquetas {*id*} y {*name*} del input estableciendo el mismo valor para ambas. Como se ve en tu archivo registro_papers.php, se espera el valor almacenado en NombrePaper, por tanto, el input debe ir así:

```
<input type=text id="NombrePaper" class="TituloPaper" name="NombrePaper">
```

**Tercer punto**: Finalmente, puedes adaptar el código que está en el archivo "registro_papers.php" al primer archivo que es el de perfiles de usuario. El código completo sería el siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Kanban</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="perfil_style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        session_start();
        if (! isset($_SESSION["usuario"])) {
            header("location: index.php");
        }

        // ---- CODIGO AÑADIDO ---- //

        // Crear una variable que almacene el mensaje de éxito o error
        $msg_papers = '';

        // Si no está vacío el valor de NombrePaper, el usuario ha enviado el formulario
        // entonces podemos agregar a la base de datos
        if (! empty($_POST["NombrePaper"])) {

            // Código proveniente del archivo registro_papers.php
            require_once("datos_conexion.php");
            $reg_paper = $_POST["NombrePaper"];

            $conexion = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass);
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                echo "Fallo al conectar a la BBDD";
                exit();
            }

            mysqli_select_db($conexion, $db_name) or die ("No se encuentra la BBDD");
            mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8");

            $query = "INSERT INTO PAPERS (PAPER_NOMBRE) VALUES('$reg_paper')";
            $res = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);

            // Se personaliza los mensajes de acuerdo al resultado del query
            if ($res == false) {
                $msg_papers = 'Error al intentar grabar el registro.';
            } else {
                $msg_papers = 'Paper registrado.';
            }
            mysqli_close($conexion);
        }

        // ---- FIN CODIGO AÑADIDO ---- //
    ?>

    <div id="main">
        <header>
            <h1>Kanban Personal</h1>
            <form action='cierre_sesion.php'>
                <input type="submit" id="CerrarSesionButton" name="CerrarSesionButton" class="btn_AddPaper" value="Cerrar Sesión"/>
            </form>
            <?php echo $_SESSION["usuario"]; ?>
        </header>

        <div id="AddPaperDiv">
            <!-- Mostrar el mensaje de la operación. Si no se envía nada, aparecerá en blanco -->
            <span style="color:red;"><?= $msg_papers; ?></span>

            <!-- Debe ir el nombre de este mismo archivo PHP y utilizar el método POST -->
            <form name="formulario" method="post" action="perfil_usuario.php">
                <!-- Mismo valor en id y name -->
                <input type=text id="NombrePaper" class="TituloPaper" name="NombrePaper">
                <button type="submit" id="AddPaperButton" class="btn_AddPaper">Añadir Paper</button> 
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="niveles">
            <div id="espera" class="nivel">
                <label>En Espera</label>
            </div>
            <div id="progreso" class="nivel">
                <label>En Progreso</label>
            </div>
            <div id="ejecutado" class="nivel">
                <label>Ejecutado</label>
            </div>                
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="perfil_script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**No olvides que todo esto debe ir en un sólo archivo.**

Como recomendación final, podrías hacer un { *if else endif* } en el archivo en el que ocurra lo siguiente:

1. Si se ha enviado el formulario, se muestre sólo el mensaje y un botón de "volver" que lo que hace es simplemente recargar la página.
2. Si no se envía nada, se muestre solamente el formulario para el envío del *NombrePaper*.

Comment: Excelente, a partir de ahora tendré muy en cuenta tus recomendaciones. 

Opté por el método GET porque como el envío se realiza desde un perfil personal al que se accede después de haberse identificado, pensé que el envío de la información sería mas rápido y la página sería más ligera. 

Voy a probar todo lo que me has dicho a ver si consigo registrar la información.

Muchas Gracias.